# How to go to a particular link in protractor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, protractor

I'm quite new to protractor. I want to explicitly tell protractor to open a particular url and do some action. How can I do that?

This is what i am currently doing right now.

```
((jasmine, driver) ->
    helpers = require(process.cwd() + '/../common/test/lib/helpers.coffee')

    timeout = helpers.defaultTimeout

    ##############  Test cases  ##################
    describe 'Going to the Connect pages and launch at dashboard', ->
        it 'Should login as admin and launch Location view', ->
            helpers.login(driver)
            expect(driver.wait ( ->
                return driver.getCurrentUrl().then (url) ->
                    return /map/.test(url) && /loc/.test(url)
            ), timeout).toBeTruthy()
        it 'should navigate to the connect page and show dashboard view', ->
            element(By.xpath("//a[@href='/connection/']")).click()
            expect(driver.wait ( ->
                return driver.getCurrentUrl().then (url) ->
                    return /dashboard/.test(url) && /conn/.test(url)
            ), timeout).toBeTruthy()

)(jasmine, browser.driver)
```

So basically I am doing some stuff already in one page. Now if I want to context switch and go to another url how can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use browser.get eg;

```
browser.get(browser.baseurl+'/link');
```

Ref https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with

```
driver.get(url);
```

where `url` is the link to the page you want to go.